# How to prevent Closure Compiler from renaming "true", "false" and "null"

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

Google Closure Compiler renames all "true", "false" and "null" occurences in code like;

```
var s = true, x = null, V = false;
```

and uses these shorthands instead; in conditions such as;

```
if (someVariable == s)
```

now; Google Analytics code defines it's own "s" variable; overriding the value "true"; and as you can see this causes a lot of problems.

I don't want to change GA code; I just want Closure Compiler to quit renaming true etc. Externs do not work.

Do you know any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you provide your own constants eg `_true_=true` and then replace with these before running though Closure Compiler?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It turns out that one can prevent Google Closure Compiler from printing out global definitions (function and/or variable) by a parameter called "output_wrapper" to the command line code such as;

```
java -jar compiler.jar --compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS --output_wrapper "(function(){%output%})();" --js input.js --js_output_file output.js
```

This way, it doesn't collide with global variables and prints all your code in an anonymous function wrapper.

Comment: I would advise using this method over adding the anonymous function in your pre-obfuscated code. This is because the Closure compiler puts the true, false and null values in the global namespace which may cause conflicts with other JS

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem here is that your code runs in the global scope/namespace, that's why things crash.

To fix it, put it inside an **anonymous function wrapper**:

```
(function() {
    // a self contained "namespace"
    var s = true; // won't be affected by the analytics code anymore       


    // expose something
    window.foo = function() {};

})(); // execute the function immediately
```

This is **the** common idiom to prevent clashes of variable names etc. If you need to make things available outside of the wrapper, simply add them as properties to the `window` object.

Don't bother to mess with closure, when you change your code it might end up giving the variables different names. Also what when there are all of a sudden more global variables on your page? All those problems are good reasons to always put your code in a wrapper like the above.

Comment: Actually, I don't rename anything. I have several files that run through the CC(closure compiler) in a single run; and all of the codes in each separate file has their own namespace with the anonymous function wrapper as in your example.

It's just, CC "strangely" renames "true", "false" and "null" in global namespace. And I can't change the way CC acts.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option in `CompilerOptions` called [aliasKeywords](http://javadoc.closure-compiler.googlecode.com/git/com/google/javascript/jscomp/CompilerOptions.html#aliasKeywords). When set to `false`, compiler will not alias 'true', 'false' and 'null'.

Comment: This was what I was looking for. For future visitors, fortunately this counter-productive feature was removed in 2015 [\[1\]](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/commit/813293c2bdf2fc230cac9371af92c5def4fb4514) [\[2\]](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/commit/dd84f24179bb433d27176e555efa3b87782ae346) (compressing duplicate symbols is what GZIP is for).