# Why does Google Closure Compiler adds variable to the global namespace when the original namespace was empty?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure

I have a long script nicely wrapped into a `(function() {/.../})()` to avoid all kind of name pollution. It is 100% typed with zero warning.

I found out that Google Closure compiler starts by redefining `i` and `j` in the global namespace which feels both unnecessary and dangerous, especially since I am compiling a script that has zero interference with the namespace. (the compiled script starts with `var i=null,j=!1;`, for compactness reasons I believe).

I can think of a work around which is to wrap it using the `--output_wrapper` but I can't think of a reason why Google would pollute the namespace like this.

Is there any?

Comment: [This is a similar example](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/closure-compiler-discuss/ZLrYebO3DDs)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent Closure Compiler from renaming "true", "false" and "null"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618571/how-to-prevent-closure-compiler-from-renaming-true-false-and-null)

Comment: Not quite, I already knew about the wrapper trick, which I mention in my post. I was looking for a reason to add a global scope while mine was empty. The answer seems to be, Closure compiler does not car whether my scope was empty or not, it just makes the assumption that it can use it.

Comment: I edited the title to be more specific about what I was looking for.

Comment: btw, there is an option to disable this global vars - http://closure-compiler.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/javascript/jscomp/CompilerOptions.html#aliasKeywords

Comment: @dragn What is the Closure option to disable use of global vars?  Your posted link is broken.  Posting the option would have been much more helpful.  I really need this - the stupid output_wrapper option does not work for me.  It somehow breaks my JS library code by "hiding" global functions (actually, "type" constructors).

Comment: @KenBeckett The url has changed a bit, see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/23225469/554966, which I've updated with correct URL and explanation. Keep in mind that this option turns off true/false/null substituion, which results in slightly larger output.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The compiler expects that it's given *all* relevant JavaScript so that it doesn't need to worry about clashes with other scripts. Therefore it assumes that it can unwrap the "unnecessary" anonymous function.

From the [FAQ](https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/wiki/FAQ#When_using_Advanced_Optimizations,_Closure_Compiler_adds_new_var):

> **When using Advanced Optimizations, Closure Compiler adds new variables to the global scope. How do I make sure my variables don't collide with other scripts on the page?**
>
> Closure Compiler's advanced optimizations mode assumes that it's ok to add new variables to the global scope.
>
> In JavaScript, it's often standard practice to wrap your code in an anonymous function, so that variables don't pollute the global scope. Closure Compiler has an `--output_wrapper` flag for exactly this purpose. Invoking it as `--output_wrapper "(function() {%output%})();"` will wrap your code in an anonymous function at compile-time.
>
> Closure Compiler users often find it easier and simpler to do this wrapping at compile-time, rather than writing the anonymous function wrapper in the original source code.

Comment: Indeed. Thinking it over, Closure never committed to not polluting the namespace. So the compiler did not bother to see whether or not I decided to protect the scope and it will add stuff to the global scope no matter how, unless I use `--output_wrapper`, which I will all the time from now on.

Comment: When compiling with `--output_wrapper` in `ECMASCRIPT5_STRICT` mode, it is worth mention that `this` value in anonymous wrapper function shall be bind manually to a `window` object: `(function() {%output%}).call(window)`. Otherwise, `this` is not referenced to a global object in 'strict mode'.

Comment: The 'output_wrapper' workaround for global scope pollution by Closure seems vastly inferior to a simple option to tell it not to pollute the global scope... AND, indeed it does NOT solve the problem in all cases.  In my situation, I have global methods (actually constructors for 'types') that are hidden by the wrapper, preventing access by external JS and breaking my library :-(

Comment: Can I set wrapper like this via `CompilerOptions` when using GCC as plugin in my Java project? I can't find a way of doing this.