# Is it safe to rename document variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I noticed that Google Closure Compiler did not rename `document` to something like `d` to reduce space.

I cannot think of a case where this would break the code (ie where `document` points to something else down the road). Actually the same goes for `window`.

Is there a reason for protecting `document` this way?

== EDIT ==

By renaming it I was thinking reassigning it. Example below.

```
var d=document;
var obj1=d.getElementById("obj1");
var obj2=d.getElementById("obj2");
... // with enough uses of document so it makes to reassign it size-wise.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What advantages does using (function(window, document, undefined) { ... })(window, document) confer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020479/what-advantages-does-using-functionwindow-document-undefined-windo)

Comment: @Bergi This is a closure-compiler specific issue (that is likely to be resolved in the future), I don't see how this is a duplicate.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: It answers the question "*What is the reason for protecting `document`?*" (though it might use a different way). But you're right, I didn't notice the GCC-specific part of the question.

Comment: The reason closure compiler protects `document` is _not_ the same as wrapping the code with an IIFE. The questions are similar in that they both discuss "protecting" document but other than that they're different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What happens?

[ProblemFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18461717/1348195)'s guess is correct.

This is a `//TODO` in the closure compiler source code. If we didn't preserve `document` and `window` and instead ran them over with `d` for example, at the moment the closure compiler does not know if it's overriding a global from another file. Like the comments say this will be resolved in the future at which point.

#### Enough words, show me the source!

If we check the closure compiler source code inside [`VariableReferenceCheck.java`](https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/browse/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/VariableReferenceCheck.java#88) we can find the following:

```
 private class ReferenceCheckingBehavior implements Behavior {

    @Override
    public void afterExitScope(NodeTraversal t, ReferenceMap referenceMap) {
      // TODO(bashir) In hot-swap version this means that for global scope we
      // only go through all global variables accessed in the modified file not
      // all global variables. This should be fixed.

      // Check all vars after finishing a scope
      for (Iterator<Var> it = t.getScope().getVars(); it.hasNext();) {
        Var v = it.next();
        checkVar(v, referenceMap.getReferences(v).references);
      }
    }
```

If we [check the hot-swap algorithm itself](https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/browse/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/VarCheck.java#108) we can see that:

```
// Note we use the global scope to prevent wrong "undefined-var errors" on
// variables that are defined in other JS files.
```

So, we can see that this is just the closure compiler not understanding the code of globals across multiple files well enough to make that replacement. You can always do the replacement yourself :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer! I believe it is not 100% consistent with the fact that Closure Compiler does add global variable to the namespace no matter whether the code did or not in the first place (cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18449503/why-does-google-closure-compiler-adds-variable-to-the-global-namespace-when-the).

Comment: Actually this not correct. Closure-compiler doesn't do this optimization because it creates BIGGER source files when compressed with gzip.

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth That sounds better, I tried deleting this answer but I get a "You cannot delete this accepted answer. MadEchet - consider accepting the other answer.

Answer (score 3):

Closure-compiler does not perform this "optimization" by default for the simple reason that it produces LARGER source when [used with gzip](https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/wiki/FAQ#Closure_Compiler_inlined_all_my_strings,_which_made_my_code_size). You can enable this optimization by turning on the `AliasExternals` pass using either the Java API or a custom build.

See https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/browse/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/AliasExternals.java#38

Answer (score 0):

I think `document` is standardized, always-global variable. To use the same way `d` it has to be global also, thus global namespace will have another "junk" variable.

It could be dangerous for not aware developers (which wont be aware of that thus it is not standard variable).

Comment: Closure Compiler introduces other (short) global names if you compile it with `ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS`

Comment: When using ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS, Closure-compiler assumes it controls the entire global namespace and so can (and does) introduce several new variable names. See https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/wiki/FAQ#When_using_Advanced_Optimizations,_Closure_Compiler_adds_new_var